# Can't ping Linux hosts on a certain subnet unless core router pings them first

Tags: routing, cisco-catalyst

We are making some changes to our network and after changing which router we use as our core router, there is a strange problem.

The problem is that there are two subnets (out of a total of more than 10) where hosts on those subnets can't be reached by hosts on other subnets, but as soon as I log on to the core switch/router (Catalyst 4507E+) and ping one of those hosts, then everyone can ping the host in question. Then about ten minutes after I've done the ping from the core router, the host that I enabled becomes unreachable from other subnets again.

The subnets are directly connected to the core.

So far my only guess is that there is some ARP problem. Pinging from the core helps these nodes successfully ARP and then the ARP cache entries time out and they are unreachable again, perhaps?

### Edit:

I've been unwittingly monitoring Windows hosts on the subnet with the main problem all along and they have never been unavailable, so it only affects Linux hosts on that subnet. That makes me think maybe this is more a question for ServerFault, since the problem is OS-specific.

Comment: Do you have dynamic arp inspection enabled (DAI) or arp access-lists?
Is all hosts connected directly to 4500? Or do you have some trunks to others switches?

Comment: Try adjust #mac-address-table aging-time for particual VLAN for much higher value and check it out. Is 4500 in VSS mode? If you have destination host going thru another switch. Does switch is connected into both 4500? or just one?

Comment: @Datagram.Network ARP inspection is disabled. None of the hosts are directly connected to the core, neither working nor non-working hosts. The core is not also an access or edge switch. The ARP entries are not aging out and disappearing on the core. I wonder if the ARP entries coming the other way on the non-working hosts might be aging out (which might be more of a serverfault question). I don't believe that the 4500 is in VSS mode because I don't know what that is. Keep in mind there are 8 other functioning subnets directly connected to the 4507.

Comment: Do you have two 4500? How they are connected into access switch? Those other subnets are on diffrent vlan I assume? VSS mode: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-6500-virtual-switching-system-1440/prod_qas0900aecd806ed74b.html

Comment: @Datagram.Network No, I have a selection of Catalyst 3850s, 2960Xs, and Dell PowerConnect 6248s. There doesn't seem to be a correlation between non-working subnets and access switches.

Comment: But it could be correlated if you using 4500 clustered how vlan is connected into 4500 cluster. Maybe vlan is not connected to active node or is not allowed on peering link (VSL) between 4500.

Comment: I would say that possibly this host is aging from CAM table rather than from ARP. Default timing is ARP=4hours and MAC=5minutes 
So I would suggest to check #show cam [mac-address] to check it out.

Comment: @Datagram.Network You were right, it **is** timing out on the CAM table. The question now is, when I try to ping the host from a workstation, why is the CAM table not re-populated?

Comment: Did you every find a solution to this problem? I seem to have the same issue. In our case it's two 4500X switches in VSS configuration. I've examined the floodset output and it seems to be empty for unicast packets for the affected vlans. We're running 3.8.3 E3. Joe
p.s. In our case though it doesn't seem to be OS specific. I'd be careful before reaching that conclusion in yours...Windows tends to be more 'chatty' so there's a higher likelihood of the mac address table on the switch being refreshed for a Windows host than a Linux one.

Comment: @JoeBorg No we haven't solved this but we are working around it while we make some changes to our network and once those changes are finished the problem should go away. It doesn't seem OS specific but it does seem like no Windows hosts have the problem. It's cropped up for other network devices like printers as well.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin My last comment above explains the end of the story is a workaround, not a resolution.

Answer (score 3):

CAM and ARP table are populeted while you ping from 4500. Is just aging faster from CAM than from ARP. If you would wait 4 hours it would time out as well from ARP. Is those 4500 clustered? 
If yes I would say that VLAN is not getting to Active node for mac address population. All the request are coming to passive node and they are dropped. Maybe STP topology for particular VLAN is blocking state to Active node.
I would compare STP topology of working vlan with not working one. Double check uplinks from access layer for this VLAN. Could be as well that VSL link between 4500 is not allowing particualr vlan. You need as well make sure that both 4500 have ports in this vlan. As well check floodset between 4500:

```
#show platform hardware floodset vlan [VLANID]
```

If both 4500's having floodset on required interfaces.

Temporary fix would be increase vlan aging time for exmaple:

```
#mac address-table aging-time 14400 vlan [VLANID]
```

Comment: There is no cluster. I'm going to try the aging time workaround for now and see if I can run down the real cause. Looks like the floodset output is correct.

Comment: So in your core you are having single 4500? Or two seperate with HSRP, VRRP or GLBP?

Comment: Wow. How can I answer this question once and for all? Yes, just one 4500.

Comment: Than I would check out STP topology for particual VLAN and use SPAN to confirm arp flows. temporary fix: you can apply #mac address-table aging-time 14400 vlan [VLANID]

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be unable to ping from different subnets host machine . But able to ping from core switch where subnets directly connected networks .

Your are preciouly able to ping from core switch because it is directly connected network.we can see ARP table in core switch maping IP address to directy connected  subnets  host IP address . Where as unable to ping from another subnet hosts because check for any access-list  Configured on core switch for any restriction.